# Python socket not accepting external connections

Tags: python, sockets

I have a python socket that is supposed to be listening to all incoming sockets on port 2022 and I have port forwarding enabled as well as a dynamic DNS service. When I am connected to the same network and I try to connect to my pc using the pc's IP address it works like a charm but when I try to use the public IP of my network it won't work although I have done proper port forwarding. Here is my code, it stucks on the last line and doesn't accept any connections outside the network:

```
  IPC= '0.0.0.0'
  PORTC =2022
  client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  client_socket.bind((IPC,PORTC))
  client_socket.listen(5)
  connection =client_socket.accept()[0].makefile('wb')
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled?

Comment: I have iptables firewall but I disabled it.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall logs if a connection attempt from outside is making it to the firewall? Have you checked if the connection is indeed being attempted to forward to your PC?

Comment: As I am new to linux i don't know how to check firewall logs but the logs on the router show the connection being forwarded indeed

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect from a different PC inside your private network, then there's nothing wrong with your Python code. It's almost certain that there's something wrong with your router or the port forwarding config.

Make sure that you've re-reviewed your port forwarding settings and perhaps try restarting the router (be careful to verify your internally assigned IP addresses haven't changed if you go this route).

Comment: Yes when using TCP I can connect from a different PC but only if I used the local IP of the other machine as the destination address, if I used the Public IP of the network along with port forwarding, no connection can be established although it works with UDP so i know my port forwarding settings are not the problem

Comment: Assuming that the local IP is `192.168.2.10`, you have your router listening on port X (any random port), and forwarding to 192.168.2.10:2022. Then you are connecting to your public IP with port X and what happens? Times out?

Comment: Yes it times out because the other end doesn't connect although in the intrusion detection log on the router it appears that the connection was forwarded to the right destination

Comment: "intrusion detection log" - are you sure this isn't blocking the connection attempt? The UDP connection is also appearing in this log?

Comment: Yes they both appear as accepted and forwarded to the right IP adress